# Is it possible to make a pseudo-global promise rejection handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, es6-promise, fetch-api

`fetch()` is a great improvement over the classic `XMLhttpRequest()` However I was wondering if I add `window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => ···);` to my `index.android.js` and `index.ios.js` could I theoretically remove all of my `.catch()` from my promise chains and make a pseudo  global promise rejection handler? I am building a react native app that relies heavily on api calls, many of which are authenticated with user tokens. When a user logs in a token is stored in asynchronous storage, but each token will expire after a certain amount of time. if a user opens the app and unwittingly attempts to make a call that requires authentication with an expired token I would like the user to be routed to the login page regardless of what call was made, or what component the call is in. I currently have each individual promise chain handling unauthenticated calls on their own. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It seems plausible. What happened when you tried?

Comment: I haven't yet, I want to do it on a new branch just in case it doesn't work, so I am just finishing my current pull request, I'll try it in an hour. If no one else responds in that time I will post the conclusion and resolve the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom abstraction on top of `fetch`, which will provide a way of communicating with API and also have some business logic, which for you case is to request an auth token or make a redirect. Then you use this abstraction in the rest of the code to make API calls. Here is a small example to demonstrate the idea:

```
export default function request(url, options = {}) {
  const req = fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      // Global response handler

      // ...

      // Hand response down the promise chain
      return response;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // Global error handler

      // Check error status and (make redirect/request auth token)

      // Throw error down the promise chain if needed
      throw err;
    });

    // Returns a promise
    return req;
}
```

Then you use it in your code like `fetch()`, but instead you'll be able to modify and extend it for you needs any time.

```
request('http://example.com/api/post/1')
  .then((response) => {
    // "response" has whatever you returned from global handler
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // "err" is whatever you've thrown from global handler
  });
```

Comment: That's a good idea, I will probably do that if I can't get the watcher to work.